# Using "would" multiple times in a sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs, sentence-structure, subjunctives, sentence-usage

Is it OK to use "would" this many times in a sentence?

> "I remember how I **would** always wish the creative writing class to end quickly so that I **wouldn't** have to show the teacher what I wrote."

Comment: I agree. I also like how you wrote "wish the creative writing class to end" instead of "wish the creative writing class would end", which would put the "would" count up to 3.

Comment: The correct amount of times to use would in a sentence is not a number. It is the amount of times it is grammatically correct and stylistically warranted to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically correct, but maybe not the best stylistic choice.  You're speaking in the passive voice, instead of of the active.

"I remember how I always wished the creative writing class would end quickly so I wouldn't have to show the teacher what I wrote."

"I remember how I always wished the creative writing class to end quickly so the teacher wouldn't see what I wrote."

I think "I remember how" is a bit wordy though. Try:

"I always wished the creative writing class would end quickly so I wouldn't have to show the teacher what I wrote."

"I always wished the creative writing class would end quickly so the teacher wouldn't want to see what I wrote."

Comment: "I would always wish..." is ***not*** **passive voice**.  It's called "subjunctive mood".

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly normal to try to avoid (unwanted) repetition in a sentence. However, if the message you want to transmit cannot be made without repetitions, then use them.

In this case (using "would"), there isn't ant replacement / synonym, so it is perfectly fine to use it.

Another similar example is using the definite article:

> **the** color of **the** button of **the** jacket of **the** captain of **the** ship

Although the example may seem "forced", you cannot express the idea correctly without repeating the definite article. Of course, you may use some trick, e.g.:

> of **the** ship's captain

and you reduce the count by 1, but repetition will still occur.

Or (to go completely nuts, probably breaking some rules of English), we could get rid of the articles like this:

> the ship's captain's jacket's button's color

but the only real achievement is replacing one repetition (the) with another repetition ('s). Why? Because the message to be transmitted requires this.

Answer (score -1):

"I remember how I always wished the creative writing class to end quickly so that I wouldn't have to show the teacher what I wrote."

using wished instead of would wish is because you did make that wish in the past.